# Are there public email to SMS gateways?

Tags: email, sms

I'm looking for a simple way to send an alert SMS in case there is something wrong with our servers. Best way would be to send email to some kind of a public SMS gateway, which would then forward the message to mobile phone.

Naturally the service does not have to be free, but affordable (like 0,1 euros per SMS) and preferably prepaid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used [Clickatell](http://www.clickatell.com/) in the past to do this, with good results. Its not free but its pretty cheap to purchase a batch of messages. It offers email to SMS, plus a pretty good API if you want to do something programmaticly with it.